# The recorded surface contact force of DRAKE with the hydroelastic model appears to be confusing

Tags: python, simulation, collision-detection, drake

#### update on July 12

The confusing contact force seems coming from importing packages. Maybe from the package "manipulation". Anyway, I build a new virtual environment and install latest DRAKE, the contact forces become correct. I also updated in github https://github.com/lllllyang/a-demo-for-drake

However, the contact torques are still confusing. The expected contact torque in this simple demo should be only in the y axis, which means tau_y = 1N*0.05m/2=0.025 Nm, while tau_x=tau_z=0 Nm. But the recorded contact torques are [tau_x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv79u.png), [tau_y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXjNH.png),[tau_z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njMIP.png). Even I change different applied force, the torques are still not what I expect.

Moreover, in this visualisation[force arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG2v7.png), the blue arrow points to a wrong direction.

#### update on July 11

I upload my code and .sdf file to github.
https://github.com/lllllyang/a-demo-for-drake

#### Revised question

Thanks for your prompt response!

Reply to Q1: My python code for this demo is here,

```py
def Addfloor(plant):
    parser = Parser(plant)
    floor_path= "./verification_floor.sdf"
    floor=parser.AddModelFromFile(floor_path)
    plant.WeldFrames(plant.world_frame(), plant.GetFrameByName("paddle2", floor),  
                   RigidTransform(RotationMatrix.MakeXRotation(np.pi*0/180),
                                    [0,0,0]))
    return floor

def AddBox(plant):
    parser = Parser(plant)
    box_path = "./verification_box.sdf"
    my_box = parser.AddModelFromFile(box_path)
                                           
    false_body1 = plant.AddRigidBody(
        "false_body1", my_box, SpatialInertia(0, [0, 0, 0],
                                              UnitInertia(0, 0, 0)))
    false_body2 = plant.AddRigidBody(
        "false_body2", my_box, SpatialInertia(0, [0, 0, 0],
                                              UnitInertia(0, 0, 0)))
    joint_x = plant.AddJoint(
        PrismaticJoint("joint_x", plant.world_frame(),
                       plant.GetFrameByName("false_body1"), [1, 0, 0], -5, 5))
    plant.AddJointActuator("joint_x", joint_x)
    joint_z = plant.AddJoint(
        PrismaticJoint("joint_z", plant.GetFrameByName("false_body1"),
                       plant.GetFrameByName("false_body2"), [0, 0, 1], -5, 5))
    plant.AddJointActuator("joint_z", joint_z)
    
    joint_theta = plant.AddJoint(
        RevoluteJoint("joint_theta", plant.GetFrameByName("false_body2"),
                       plant.GetFrameByName("paddleh"), [0, 1, 0], 0.5))
    plant.AddJointActuator("joint_theta", joint_theta)
    return my_box


class Box_on_floor(LeafSystem):

    def __init__(self, plant):
        LeafSystem.__init__(self)
        self._plant = plant
        self.contF_box=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0])
        self.all_command=np.array([0,0,0])
        self.count=0
        self.DeclareAbstractInputPort("contact_results",
                                      AbstractValue.Make(ContactResults()))
        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort("actuation", 3, self.CalcOutput)

    def CalcOutput(self, context, output):
        self.count=self.count+1
        g = self._plant.gravity_field().gravity_vector()[[0,2]]
        results = self.get_input_port(0).Eval(context)
        if results.num_hydroelastic_contacts() == 0:
            self.contF_box = np.vstack((self.contF_box, [0,0,0,0,0,0]))
        for i in range(results.num_hydroelastic_contacts()):
            info = results.hydroelastic_contact_info(i)
            this_F=info.F_Ac_W().get_coeffs()
            self.contF_box = np.vstack((self.contF_box, this_F))    
        k=1/1000
        if self.count < 1500:
            F=[0,0,0]  
        elif self.count < 2500:
            F=[k*(self.count-1500), 0, 0]
        else:
            F=[k*(2500-1500), 0, 0]
        output.SetFromVector(F) 
        self.all_command = np.vstack((self.all_command, F))

# before plant finish 
builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.001)
box = Addfloor(plant)
my_box = AddBox(plant)
plant.GetJointByName("joint_x").set_default_translation(0)
plant.GetJointByName("joint_z").set_default_translation(0.2)
plant.Finalize()

MeshcatVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph, meshcat)
ContactVisualizer.AddToBuilder(
    builder, plant, meshcat,
    ContactVisualizerParams(radius=0.005))

# add system
controller = builder.AddSystem(Box_on_floor(plant))
zoh = builder.AddSystem(ZeroOrderHold(0.001,AbstractValue.Make(ContactResults())))
builder.Connect(plant.get_contact_results_output_port(), zoh.get_input_port(0))
builder.Connect(zoh.get_output_port(0), controller.get_input_port(0))
builder.Connect(controller.get_output_port(0), plant.get_actuation_input_port())
logger = LogVectorOutput(plant.get_state_output_port(my_box), builder)


# start diagarm
diagram = builder.Build()
simulator = Simulator(diagram)
context = simulator.get_mutable_context()
simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(0.5) # it defines the time step
simulator.AdvanceTo(6); # total time
```

Reply to Q2: The weight of box is just 1kg.

Reply to Q3: As you can see in the code, I set 3 joints to box. The joint in the x-axis applies a linearly increasing force to the box using the code "output.SetFromVector(F)". To record the sensed contact force, I use "hydroelastic_contact_info().F_Ac_W().get_coeffs()".

In 'my old questions' I uploaded the result figures.

Please feel free to let me know if there's anything I can do to make the question clearer. Thank you for reading!

#### my old question

I am currently utilizing DRAKE for simulations. I have conducted a test on the function "Contact_F=results.hydroelastic_contact_info().F_Ac_W().get_coeffs()" by a simple scenario. In this scenario, there is a box resting on a floor, and a linearly increasing force is applied to the box, ensuring that the maximum external force does not exceed the maximum friction. However, upon comparing the recorded Contact_F with the provided force, I have found that they are not equal.
There is only one pair of contact surface so I should record the correct contact result.[a box rests on a floor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gsZQ.png)[recorded force v.s. applied force](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZHaY.png)

I hope the contact force from contact surface should totally equal to the force I apply on the box, since the box is static state. My box model and floor model are both .sdf with hydroelastic parameters.

Comment: Several questions:
1. Can you make the demo available. It's generally easier to answer these questions when looking at code.
2. What's the mass of the box?
3. How are you measuring the applied force?

(Admittedly, these latter questions are easily answered if the first question's answer is "yes".)

Comment: @Sean Curtis Thanks for your comments, I revised my question. Would you like to have a look on it?

Comment: I'm curious if you are applying the force through the center of mass of the box. I assume that's the purpose of moving the joint z's initial translation, but it's hard to tell without information on the sdformat files.

Comment: @Xuchen Han Thanks for your comment. Yes, the force is applied through the center. The purpose is applying force on the joint x but not exceed the max friction force. I hope the contact feedback should equal to the applied force. The sdf. file is just simple box, nothing special. I set both friction coefficient as 0.9.

Comment: @LinYANG, could you provide a complete example we can run? that is, there is no "import" in your example (I can add them, but it'd be nice if the example was self contained), and also provide the SDFs you used. Many things could've gone wrong, but impossible to tell without a full reproduction. Thanks!

Comment: An update on this @LinYANG, I created my own SDF files to run your example, and I was not able to reproduce the problem. That is, I do get the correct contact forces in this case. Would you be able to provide a complete self contained example? please also make it minimal. In this case for instance there is no reason to have a zero order hold nor the logger. Could you also provide an example that creates the one file you use to plot results from? I wonder if the problem is in the way the results are transfered to the plot?

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks for your reply! I upload the demo and .sdf code to github. https://github.com/lllllyang/a-demo-for-drake. 
I use zero order holder because I need utilize real-time contact force feedback later. So in this demo, I keep it and plan to use it in the future work.

Comment: I'd appreciate you take the time to make a "self contained" python script (not even a notebook). In this case, I do not have module "manipulation", as a generic Drake developer you can only expect me to have Drake in my computer. The code you provided has a typo, "paddleh" where it should be "paddle". All together, this does not run. 
What I did. I opened in Jupyther, saved to a single .py file, fixed typos and rerun. My plot of forces in x do match. Could you rerun this? I cannot reproduce the error you observe.

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks for your suggestion, I build a new python environment and downloaded only Drake. Now the contact forces are correct but the contact torques are still confusing. Could you observe these torques? I update this question with new results.
I also checked the typo and rewrite code into a py file instead of notebook. I updated them in github. Could you rerun this? Thanks for your time!